# How to stop Scrolling when a popup is open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup div which is present on the center of the screen and when the pop-up is visible the scrolling should be disable. How do I do that using jQuery and css. I already tried using an overlay over the browser. However this is not working.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Jquery popup</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 #popup
            {
    display: none;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
    margin-top: -240px;
    border: thin dashed #8f44ad;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #2d3e50;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
            }
  .close
{
    float: right;
    color: #2a80b9;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  #overlay
            {
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1000;
                background: #96a6a6;

            }
#style {
    background-color: #2d3e50;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#main {
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    border: thin dashed #FFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
#main input
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: #16a086;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#main input:hover
{
    background-color:#27ae61;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="style">
<div id="popup">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<br />
<br />
<div style=" width:600px float:left" align="center ">
Click on the button above to close this box
</div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="main">
<div style="width:600px;float:left">
<span>This is the basic view of the page</span>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div style="width:600px;float:left">
<input type="submit" value="Click Here To view the popup" id="showpopup" />
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("input#showpopup").click(function(){
                                $("div#overlay").fadeIn('500');       
                                $("div#popup").delay('800');
                                $("div#popup").fadeIn('500');         
                           }); 

    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
                                $("div#popup").fadeOut('500');      
                                $("div#overlay").delay('500');
                                $("div#overlay").fadeOut('500');
                           });
                });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19):

When you open the popup, change the css **`overflow`** property to **`hidden`** like

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden')
```

When you close it, change back to normal

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto')
```

**Complete Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("input#showpopup").click(function () {
         $("div#overlay").fadeIn('500');
         $("div#popup").delay('800');
         $("div#popup").fadeIn('500');
         $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');  //ADD THIS
     });

     $(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
         $("div#popup").fadeOut('500');
         $("div#overlay").delay('500');
         $("div#overlay").fadeOut('500');
         $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');  //ADD THIS
     });
 });
```

### [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/8GJd4/)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to disable full page scrolling, i.e the body.

Set `overflow:hidden` CSS attribute for `<body>` tag, when the popup is enabled and set it as `auto` when popup is disabled.

Comment: is there any way to prevent page resizing while  setting `overflow:hidden` ..?

Comment: Use `max-width` / `min-width` and similar for heights?

Answer (score 2):

Add overflow:hidden to the css of the body:

```
$('#show_my_popup').click(function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

then remove the overflow when it closes:

```
...
$('body').css('overflow', '');
```

This will make the page jump a few pixels to the right if you have a scrollbar though, so you can add this to avoid it:

```
$('#show_my_popup').click(function(){
    //add right margin to keep page from jumping right
    $('body').css('margin-right', (window.innerWidth - $('body').width()) + 'px');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

then when you close the popup:

```
...
$('body').css('overflow', '');
$('body').css('margin-right', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:hidden`  on body element when dialog opens.

Answer (score 0):

Can archive by jQuery. Overflow won't work on IOS.  Below are the code to enable and disable background scroll.

1. Disable Body touchmove.

   ```
   $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e){
                       e.preventDefault(); 
                       // alert('prevent scroll');         
                   });
   ```
2. Enable Popup container scroll.

   ```
   $('.mfp-auto-cursor .mfp-content').bind('touchmove', function(e){
                       e.stopPropagation();
                       // alert('allow scroll');
                   });
   ```
3. After close the popup enable body scroll again.

   ```
   $(document).unbind();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a situation where you could apply position fixed to the container of your pop up, along with a higher z-index than the rest of your content. Allowing the scroll to remain but your pop-up will sit over the top of the page?

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Ta, J.